# value counts not working with a column filter in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, count, multiple-columns

everyone I was trying to count the number of Yes answered in a column depending on the answer from another previous column to generate pie charts so I'm having problems with this because is giving me counts in boolean like in image below, (This is my codeline):

```
answers = ['Yes']
hello = (df['Are you okay?']== 'No') &(df['Are yu sad?'].isin(answers))
```

[image]

Actually I just want that the result will be something like this:

```
Yes 
110
```

EDIT:

This is my result and in red the thing that I want

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If need count values of boolean mask use `sum` for processing `True`s:

```
answers = ['Yes']
hello = (df['Are you okay?']== 'No') &(df['Are yu sad?'].isin(answers))

df = pd.DataFrame({answers[0]: hello.sum()})
```

If ned count `Are yu sad?` column by condition `df['Are you okay?']== 'No'` use:

```
df1 = (df.loc[df['Are you okay?']== 'No', 'Are yu sad?']
         .value_counts()
         .rename_axis('Vals')
         .reset_index(name='Count'))
```

Comment: Yes I need something more like the second one : If ned count Are yu sad? column by condition df['Are you okay?']== 'No'.

But I only need the row 0 so How can I just leave the Yes count? I'll edit the post at the end

Answer (score 0):

`hello` in this case, is an array of boolean. Apply the array to original dataframe.

```
answers = ['Yes']
hello = df[(df['Are you okay?']== 'No') &(df['Are yu sad?'].isin(answers))]
```

then apply `hello.value_counts()`

Comment: That's what I did at the end